# How to add new properties to class constructor, if there are exist same param names?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

I'm trying to make object: Cube { length: 1, surfaceArea: 6, volume: 1 }
But it now work because the class have same params.
If I delete "set surfaceArea...", constructor works.
I need a class, that can assign two parameters, if you have another one. So I stuck at first step.
`

```
class Cube {
  constructor(length) {
    this.length = length;
    this.surfaceArea = length ** 2 * 6;
    this.volume = length ** 3;
  }
  set surfaceArea (value) {

  }
  get surfaceArea () {

  }
  set volume (value) {

  }
  get volume () {

  }
}
var cube = new Cube(1);
console.log(cube)
```

`

How to build this class.

Comment: Remove the lines setting `surfaceArea` and `volume` from the constructor, and make the calculations in the getters. `surfaceArea` setter is not a sufficient setter, as the value depends on `length` only, and is calculated in the getter.

Comment: Alternatively, use [private class features](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields): `#surfaceArea; #volume;` as class elements and `this.#surfaceArea = length ** 2 * 6; this.#volume = length ** 3;` in the constructor. The getters and setters won’t conflict with these.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with what you have is that you have setters that do nothing and getters that do nothing. So `this.surfaceArea = ___` is a no-op, and if you read from the `surfaceArea` property, you'll always get `undefined` (the implicit return value of the `surfaceArea` getter). (And both of those are true for `volume` as well.)

You have to either:

- Store the values somewhere, or
- Perform the calcuation in the getters

If you decide to store the values somewhere, you have a couple of options for where to store them: public properties or [private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#private_fields). You'll also want to make `length` an accessor property instead of a data property as it is now, because otherwise assigning a different value to `length` makes your `surfaceArea` and `volume` incorrect. (And doing that means you'll need a place to store `length`, since if the `length` property itself is an accessor, you nee somewhere else to keep its current value.)

If you decide to do the calculations every time `surfaceArea` or `volume` is *accessed*, remove the setters for them and don't assign to `surfaceArea` or `volume` in the constructor (since they're entirely dynamic, derived from `length`).

I'm purposefully not including code in this answer because I suspect this is some kind of class assignment or similar where the expectation is that you'll write the code. So instead I'm giving you pointers to how you might do that. More about that here: [*How do I ask and answer homework questions?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)